# Resume downloading while using System.Net.ConnectStream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, download

I am downloading file using `System.Net.ConnectStream`. However to support pause functionality for downloading,what I am doing is create new connection on click of start as follows:

```
this.InputStream = CreateLink(this.URL);
```

In CreateLink I check whether file is updated at server and return the corresponding stream for downloading.
I download file as chunk of bytes as:

```
InputStream.Read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
```

The Problem is it starts reading from beginning and not where it is paused.Also I am unable to use `this.InputStream.Position = CurrentPosition;` to set position of InputStream since it is nonseekable.Moreover,Stream supports 'Accept-Ranges' as 'bytes'

So, How can I begin downloading from paused position?

**Update:**

'this' refers to the instance of downloader as:

```
Downloader downloader = new Downloader();
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)GetRequest(path);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 downloader.InputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: I think you should post more of your code, specifically, clarify what is the class that "this" references, what type InputStream is, etc.

Comment: I have added more code

Comment: Well, from reading about Stream class in MSDN documentation I see the following: "Streams can support seeking. Seeking refers to querying and modifying the current position within a stream. Seek capability depends on the kind of backing store a stream has. For example, network streams have no unified concept of a current position, and therefore typically do not support seeking." I think it means that setting position inside a network stream is not supported, but if you know the CurrentPosition you need, can't you just use: `InputStream.Read(buffer+CurrentPosition, offset, bytesToRead);` ?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929733/how-do-i-use-system-net-connectstream

Comment: @rene there is no relation at all