# Write ConnectStream into MemoryStream

Tags: c#, stream, copy, memorystream

I am using this code to write the connectstream to memorystream:

```
        buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            mStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
```

But I always get an error:

```
there was a problem reading this document (109)
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8929947/3227403

Answer (score 1):

After the loop is completed, the MemoryStream is left positioned to the end of the stream.  Reading from it isn't going to produce anything.  Add:

```
  mStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Well, that's accurate, that comment was completely unhelpful to help me help you.  Of course I have no idea what a "document" might be and what error "109" could mean.  Contact the library owner or author for support.

Comment: The document is a pdf document, and the error is shown inside Adobe reader: "there was a problem reading this document (109)"